# Multisite Ajax serialize return error [object Object]

Tags: functions, multisite, ajax

Working on custom WP theme, i'd like to add some "add_testimony" linked to custom post.

Form is real simple, here it is :

```
    <!-- Add testimonial -->
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form role="form" id="addTestimonialForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastname"><?php __('Name', 'vulcanet'); ?>Name :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstname"><?php __('Firstname', 'vulcanet'); ?>Firstname :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email"><?php __('Email', 'vulcanet'); ?>Email :</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="comment"><?php __('Comment', 'vulcanet'); ?>Comment :</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="comment" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo get_site_url(1);?>">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_testimonial"><?php __('Submit', 'vulcanet'); ?>Submit</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="cancel_testimonial"><?php __('Cancel', 'vulcanet'); ?>Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now i have in `functions.php` this code, to add Ajax :

```
function add_js_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'testimonies', get_template_directory_uri().'/custom/js/testimonies.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'geolocation', get_template_directory_uri().'/custom/js/geolocation.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

    // pass Ajax Url to testimonies.js
    wp_localize_script('testimonies', 'ajaxurl', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
    wp_localize_script('geolocation', 'ajaxurl', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js_scripts');
```

So my testimony function looks like this :

```
function add_testimonial_ajax(){
    // Create post object
    $testimonial = array(
      'post_title'    => $_POST['firstname'].' '.$_POST['lastname'],
      'post_content'  => $_POST['comment'],
      'post_status'   => 'draft',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type' => 'testimony'
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $testimonial );
    //Send email to admin
    $site_title = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    $site_url = network_site_url( '/' );
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description' );
    $headers = 'From: '.$site_title.' <'.$site_title.'@'.$site_title.'.com>' . "\r\n";
    $admin_email = get_option('admin_email');
    $subject = 'Nouveau témoignage enregistré sur le site '.$site_title.'';
    $message = '
        <p>Bonjour,</p>
        <p>Un nouveau témoignage vient d\'être enregistré en brouillon sur le site '.$site_title.'.</p>
        <p>Merci de prendre le temps de vous connecter et de vérifier la validité de ce témoignage</p>
    ';
    wp_mail( $admin_email, $subject, $message, $headers );
    wp_die( 'ok' );
}
add_action('wp_ajax_add_testimonial', 'add_testimonial_ajax');
```

Now JS script :

```
    // This does the ajax request
$("#addTestimonialForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var dataString = $("#addTestimonialForm").serialize();
    var firstname = $(this).data('firstname');
    var lastname = $(this).data('lastname');
    var comment = $(this).data('comment');
    console.log(dataString);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action':'add_testimonial_ajax',
            'data' : dataString
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data) {
            console.log('success = '+ data);
            var delay = 6000;
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#add_testimony_response').html('Votre témoignage a été mis en attente de validation');
            }, delay);
            return false;
            event.preventDefault();
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log('error = '+ errorThrown);
            return false;
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Problem is console returns me error = [object Object] but console.log datastring returns fine.

Any idea ? First time using Ajax on native WP, i was used to code standalone scripts...

Demo can be seen at http://dev.team-ever.com/auto/temoignages/

Comment: You set data type json. how about your output from function `add_testimonial_ajax`?

Comment: How should i output data considering i'm thinking data is not get by Wp function ?

Comment: if it is front-end and user not log in then you need [`wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side)

Comment: I've just added unlogged function, same result

Comment: actually your function get the value but as my first comment I need you evaluate your output data, since it return in html (wp_die). I suggest to use [`wp_send_json_success`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_success) or [`wp_send_json_error`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_error/).